# Does the number of iterations of the 'for' loop change if the second argument changes in one of the iterations?

Tags: c++

i've this code here:

```
for(i = openGates[0]; i < closeGates[0]; i++) {
    if(str[i] == '(') {
        closeGates.removeFirst();
        openGates.removeAt(1);        
    }
}
```

If brace found, `closeGates[0]`'s value will change. Will it change the number of iterations?

Comment: Yes it will. All variables are evaluated at every iteration.

Comment: You could test this by writing a 10 line program.

Comment: @drescherjm yes i could, but i dont have simple IDE rn

Comment: You can try an online one like: ideone.com

Comment: @Pere_Strelka there are plenty of online compilers you can use: ideone.com, godbolt.org, onlinegdb.com, coliru.stacked-crooked.com, just to name a few.

Comment: @drescherjm wow sorry didnt know it exists for c++

Comment: @AdrianMole How embarassing. I need to get a new pair of improved glasses :(

Comment: The best glasses are beer glasses! :)

Comment: This question *may* be a good place for a full explanation of `for` loop properties (if there's no suitable duplicate). Also maybe worth mentioning the "as if" rule so that compilers are allowed to optimize cases like `i < strlen(str)` if it can see that `str` isn't changed in the loop's body. But it's already way past my bedtime, so I'll leave it to somebody else...

Comment: I think the question is legitimate, as in some other languages, the behavior would be different. In Lua for example, the bounds for the `for` loop are evaluated once, if you set the counter variable inside the loop that doesn't change the count. Also, I can imagine that in C or C++ the behavior _could_ have been left undefined, to let more optimization opportunities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `iteration-expression` is executed after every iteration of the loop.
Reference for this answer :
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, no one decided to answer and I want to close this question so: yes, in C++ 'for' loop evaluates its conditions before every iteration thus the number of the iterations might change.

Comment: Actually, the `condition` part of the `for` statement is evaluated ***before*** every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @AdrianMole well, you are right and technically I am too
but fixed